# Ionic Angular2 own Component

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

My component html:

```html
<div>
  {{text}}
  {{percentLeft}}
  {{innerColor}}
</div>
```

My Component's TS File

```ts
import { Component,Input } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Generated class for the TimeLeftBarComponent component.
 *
 * See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentMetadata-class.html
 * for more info on Angular Components.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'time-left-bar',
  templateUrl: 'time-left-bar.html'
})
export class TimeLeftBarComponent {
   @Input('text') text: string;
   @Input('percentLeft') percentLeft: number;
   @Input('innerColor') innerColor: string; 

   constructor() {}

}
```

How I call this component:

```html
<time-left-bar [percentLeft]="50" [text]="text" [innerColor]="black">
</time-left-bar>
```

It's only displaying the first parameter I enter,

for Example:

```html
<time-left-bar [percentLeft]="50" [text]="text"  [innerColor]="black">
</time-left-bar>
```

Outputs just `50`

```html
<time-left-bar [text]="text"  [innerColor]="black" [percentLeft]="50">
</time-left-bar>
```

Outputs just `text`

```html
<time-left-bar  [innerColor]="black" [percentLeft]="50" [text]="text">
</time-left-bar>
```

Outputs just `black`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you change it like this: First declare a property with the number value: `public aNumber = 50` and then in the view `<time-left-bar [percentLeft]="aNumber" text="'text'"  innerColor="'black'">`? Since  `text` and the `innerColor` are just strings, you don't need the property binding (please notice that instead of sending `text` I send `'text'` with single quotes).

Comment: its working with single quotes ty!

Comment: If the answer solves the issue, could you please mark it as the accepted answer so we can close the issue? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

> If you add [] then Angular evaluates the value as expression. When
>   there is no property with that name on your component's class or it
>   doesn't have a value then it will result to undefined or null.

So if you just want to send a string value for `text` and `innerColor`, use single quotes:

```
<time-left-bar ... [text]="'text'" [innerColor]="'black'"></time-left-bar>
```

A better approach would be to create properties for these values instead and use that name (without single quotes):

```
public aNumber = 50;
public aText = 'some text';
public aColor = 'black';
```

And in the view:

```
<time-left-bar [text]="aText" [innerColor]="aColor" [percentLeft]="aNumber">
</time-left-bar>
```